# Strange behavior with structure in C++

Tags: c++

I have a strange behavior that I can't understand with data in a structure.
See my code:

```
typedef struct _Foo {
    char refDossier[12];
    char refDossier62 [9];
} Foo;

string refStr = "157809110000";
string ref62Str = "02mFqwTo";

strncpy(fooStruct.refDossier, refStr.c_str(), sizeof (fooStruct.refDossier));
strncpy(fooStruct.refDossier62, ref62Str.c_str(), sizeof (fooStruct.refDossier62));

cout << "REF DOSSIER 62: " << fooStruct.refDossier62 << endl;
cout << "REF DOSSIER: " << fooStruct.refDossier << endl;
```

Here the result:

```
REF DOSSIER 62: 02mFqwTo
REF DOSSIER: 15780911000002mFqwTo
```

I don't understand why the value of `fooStruct.refDossier62` appears whyle you print the value of `fooStruct.refDossier`.
I know that the data of a structure are contiguous in memory but in my point of view this is not the reason of this strange behavior.

When I run the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i< sizeof (fooStruct.refDossier); i++) {
   cout << fooStruct.refDossier[i];
 }
 cout << endl;
 for (int j = 0; j< sizeof (fooStruct.refDossier62); j++) {
   cout << fooStruct.refDossier62[j];
 }
```

I have a correct output:

```
157809110000
02mFqwTo
```

There is therefore no memory overwriting, which I feared.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Also be aware of undefined behavior which means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely on the output of a program that has UB, the program may just crash.

Comment: You're forgetting that C-style strings are really called ***null-terminated** strings*. Your arrays needs space for the null-terminator character `'\0'` as well. Since your arrays are not null-terminated, they can't be used by any functions that expects strings, and that include the stream output operators.

Comment: `"157809110000"` is too long for 12-`char` array because a room for terminating null-character is required.

Comment: Any ideas? `std::string` !

Comment: On a totally different note, please read [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) The C++ specification doesn't allow you to define a symbol like `_Foo`.

Comment: Also be aware that [`strncpy()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) do NOT put terminating null-character if the input is too long.

Comment: Minor point: you don't have to do the `typedef struct ... { ... } name;` dance in C++. `struct name { ... };` works just fine. The rules are different from C.

Comment: @MikeCAT it was the problem ! Many thanks.

Comment: Although the question is well asked and well formed, I suspect it's getting downvotes because it's a basic, common problem and therefore the low question score reflects a lack of research as opposed to a poorly asked question.

Comment: Unless I have a measurable and concrete performance need, I always prefer `snprintf()` over `strncpy()` as to protect myself against a forgotten '\0'.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of why you need to be careful with `strncpy`.

```
strncpy(fooStruct.refDossier, refStr.c_str(), sizeof (fooStruct.refDossier));
```

This will copy up to `sizeof (fooStruct.refDossier)` bytes to the destination buffer.  While this prevents the buffer from being overrun, if there are at least `sizeof (fooStruct.refDossier)` bytes to be copied, which there is in this case, a null terminated byte will **not** be added.

So `fooStruct.refDossier` doesn't contain a null terminated string, and attempting to use a string function on it will result in reading off the end of the array, triggering [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The field should be made one element larger:

```
typedef struct _Foo {
    char refDossier[13];
    char refDossier62 [9];
} Foo;
```

And `strncpy` should copy one less than the buffer size, and a null terminated should be explicitly added.

```
strncpy(fooStruct.refDossier, refStr.c_str(), sizeof (fooStruct.refDossier)-1);
fooStruct.refDossier[sizeof (fooStruct.refDossier)-1] = 0
strncpy(fooStruct.refDossier62, ref62Str.c_str(), sizeof (fooStruct.refDossier62)-1);
fooStruct.refDossier62[sizeof (fooStruct.refDossier62)-1] = 0;
```